# SQL query to select related data from two column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table 'names' filled like this

```
 slno          from        to  
  1              a          e 
  2              a          b
  3              c          d
  4              c          e 
  .......  like this
```

These all a b c d e are logged in user need to show who they are related
now i need a select statement to select the related.

```
firstly  i used 

   Select * from names where from= @zx        
   (@zx is the session )
```

by this i can get the values for only a and c.

But i need to display related data of b,d and e too  i need to use only one select command.  is there any select command to select mutually related data. as each time someone of this logged in need to show who they are related.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an inner join to reference the table twice.

```
select * 
from 
  names as t1 inner join 
  names as t2 on t1.[from] = t2.[to] 
where t1.[from]= @zx
```

If your trying to do this in a recursive kind of way, you won't be able to manage it in a single select command. You could put the logic into a stored procedure that would iterate over the dataset multiple times until your set was built and then return the full set.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want. Do you want to display the users for a session, AND the users for whom the first set of users are related by "from - to" relationship (let's call them parents/children)?

Or do you ALSO want to display those that the SECOND list of users relates to?

E.g. for this data:

```
slno   from     to
 1      a         b
 1      b         c
 1      c         d
```

Do you want to display:

- a and b
- a-b, b-c and c-d pairs?

For a-b, do:

```
 Select * from names where from= @zx        

 UNION

 -- For a large set of data, use inner join instead
 select * from names 
 where from IN
    (Select to from names where from= @zx)      
  and from= @zx
```

The second, as noted, should really be done as a join:

```
 Select * from names where from= @zx        

 UNION

 Select n2.* from names as n_from, names as n2
 where n1.from= @zx and n2.from=n1.to
```

---

For the other option, what you want is basically a recursive retrieval which uses some tree traversal algorithm.

You can not do that in **pure** SQL as far as relational data goes. You must either use a loop (in SQL or in your driver software), or, if your database allows you, you can write recursive expression which will in effect work identically.

Luckily for you, SQL Server actually allows the latter. As shown in the following excellent blog entry: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/28/sql-server-simple-example-of-recursive-cte/
 (substitute EmployeeID for to and ManagerID for from)

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
WITH Emp_CTE AS (
SELECT EmployeeID, ContactID, LoginID, ManagerID, Title, BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee
WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.ContactID, e.LoginID, e.ManagerID, e.Title, e.BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.EmployeeID = e.ManagerID
)
SELECT *
FROM Emp_CTE
GO
```

Comment: i want to display when a logged in it it display e and b

Comment: when c logged in it display d and e and when e logged in it should show a and c